# Mixing video and data streams on raspberry pi for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, raspberry-pi, klvdata

What is best way to mix data and video for machine learning on single board computer like raspberry pi?

It should be very common problem. I found there is GPMF and KLV extensions for video formats. But I fail to find someone to implment that for raspberry pi, opencv, etc.

It seems I can solve the problem by mixing 2 data streams in single file and then read that file with my own code but I wonder what is canonical solution for that kind of problem.